# Using if statement inside _vimrc file?

Tags: configuration-files, vim

I tried to create a function in my vim configuration file, so that I can "compile and run" according to file type ( I mainly work with Fortran, C and Python ). It did work except that each time after the compiled executable was ran, there would be a notification at bottom of my vim saying:

**Error detected while processing function CompileRun:
line   17:
E171:  Missing :endif**

I have no idea what "line 17" and "E171" means because they can't be related with either source file or _vimrc file, also it seems the if statement is closed. I googled a lot without finding an answer. My function is as follows:

```
map <F4> : call CompileRun()<CR>

func! CompileRun()

    if &filetype == 'fortran'
    exec "w"
    exec "!gfortran % -o %<"
    exec "!%<.exe"
    exec "i" 

    elseif &filetype == 'c'
    exec "w"
    exec "!gcc % -o %<"
    exec "!%<.exe"
    exec "i"

    elseif &filetype == 'python'
    exec "w"
    exec "!python %<.py"
    exec "i"
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: I don't get any error when copying the function body into my vim (7.3), save it as test.vim, sourcing the file and calling CompileRun()...

Comment: I also use vim 7.3, but vim always inserts part of the function into my code after I compile and run it. If this didn't happen to you, I am totally confused...

Comment: I'm guessing that you wanted to use `call feedkeys("i")` instead of `exec "i"`...

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because one of your commands throws something.

BTW, off-topic:

- have a look at `:make` and `&makeprg`
- gnumake does not required any makefile for mono-file projects ; hence just: `:make %<` will be enough, and no need to specify any `&makeprg` either. (It work for sure with C, C++, and probably fortran)
- `:exec` is completely useless in your calls.
- Are you sure you want to execute `:insert` at the end of your functions ? Try without this call.
- You can restrict your mapping to normal mode. It won't work in other modes like that =>

  `nnoremap <F4> :call Compile()<cr>`

Comment: What puzzles me most is the "Missing :endif" error. I am not familiar with vim's script and the function is based on what I found thru google. "exec" is useful because without it all the commands become comments...I execute insert so I can edit and fix the error if it happens

Comment: The "missing endif" error is typical of exception thrown within a if block. :exe, AND the quotes are perfectly useless here.